# How can I use ausearch to log the IP of a user when they modify a file over SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, logging, remote-access

My team logs in on a development server using the same root password; we have not set up separate user accounts.

I am now trying to create a log of file changes and I want to distinguish between different authors, but ausearch always returns the name of the user (so "root" always), even when I pass the rule `name_format=numeric`, which was supposed to expose the IP address instead of "root".

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This question was also asked by the OP in another online venue. This is an edited version of my answer at that other location. The inadvisability of multiple users logging in directly as root has already been addressed there, and need not be revisited.*

As I understand it, you're asking how to get the audit logs to show which IP address each logged action was taken from. Your frustration is that most audit lines don't even have `hostname` and `addr` fields, and the few that do mostly look like this:

```
node=192.168.33.9 type=USER_START msg=audit(1422241281.664:263): pid=5912 uid=0 auid=1001 ses=18 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/4 [...]
```

i.e. with unknown `hostname` and `addr` values.

The Linux audit subsystem doesn't automagically populate its entries with associated hostname/IP info; daemons like sshd have to explicitly provide them to auditd in some fashion (in the case of sshd, through PAM calls):

```
node=192.168.33.9 type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1422240837.085:202): pid=5441 uid=0 auid=501 ses=18 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="ratb" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=canton.local addr=192.168.33.36 terminal=ssh res=success'
```

User-level commands like your favorite editor won't do so at all, since they don't care where you're coming from.

Since everyone is logging in directly as the same user, you'll have to record individual `ses` ("session") numbers from the *USER_START* audit messages that sshd emits via PAM, then correlate them with the `ses` IDs of the *SYSCALL* messages for the activity you want to track. For instance, this was the audit trail for `echo hi > tmp/testing.txt` from the same SSH session as above, and so shares the same `ses` ID (18):

```
node=192.168.33.9 type=PATH msg=audit(1422241924.835:341): item=1 name="tmp/testing.txt" inode=2631940 dev=08:22 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE
node=192.168.33.9 type=PATH msg=audit(1422241924.835:341): item=0 name="tmp/" inode=2621477 dev=08:22 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
node=192.168.33.9 type=CWD msg=audit(1422241924.835:341):  cwd="/root"
node=192.168.33.9 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1422241924.835:341): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=bc62a8 a1=241 a2=1b6 a3=10 items=2 ppid=5913 pid=5921 auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts4 ses=18 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash" key=(null)
```